# Getting collection index in pseudo-class? (jquery 1.8+)

Tags: jquery, pseudo-class

I'm trying to implement a pseudo-class (in jQuery 1.8.3). Here's the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        group: $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
            var index = 0;
            return function(element) {
                index += 1;
                var num = parseInt(arg, 10);
                if (isNaN(num)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return (((index-1) % (num*2)) < num);
            }
        })
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The aim of this selector is to apply a style to "n" consecutive groups of elements, and could be used like so to color every 3 rows of a tbody ("this") in an alternate color (classed with 'alt')

```
$(this).children(':visible').has('td').filter(':group(3)').addClass('alt')
```

This works well for one tbody. But if I'm iterating on several tbodies (with a " $('..').each" construct), index is not reset in-between.
This effect could be successfully achieved in jquery 1.6, since we naturally had (in the underlying "group" function parameters) the index within the set:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        group: function(element, index, matches, set) {
            var num = parseInt(matches[3], 10);
            if (isNaN(num)) {
                return false;
            }
            return index % (num * 2) < num;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How could we achieve the same effects in jquery 1.8?

Thanks a lot for your insights!

Comment: The problem is that `var index = 0;` only executes once, right when `createPseudo` is invoked. Then it keeps getting incremented by the returned function, which has closed over it.

Comment: Asad, that's precisely the issue. How to reset the index each time we iterate on a new collection? Or is there a way to write the extension to have the index passed as a parameter (as in jquery 1.6)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `createPositionalPseudo` in [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js), but it's not exposed. By duplicating the function, I can actually use it and it worked. I simplified it to just:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  group: $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg){
    return $.expr.createPseudo(function(seed, matches){
      for (var i=0; i<seed.length; i++) 
        if (i % (arg * 2) >= arg)
          matches.push(seed[i]);
      })
  })
});
```

I create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egb3x/) for test.

I don't know the inside of Sizzle, it seems `seed` is the list of elements for the pseudo filter to process, and `matches` is the list to return, indicating which pass the filter.

The `createPositionalPseudo` also modifies `seed`, but the code above does not. It could cause problem, since I don't know what's inside, I am not sure. However, it runs okay in my test.

The JavaScript in the jsFiddle contains a `create_group_pseudo_safe`, it's not simplified. If there is any issue with simplified, that safe version function should work.

Comment: livibetter: I looked at your fiddle and also tried your code on my page. It's colored the right way (tr with th are ignored, coloring is reset at each new sub-tbody within the same table as intended) . Thanks for this good answer! I think it would be nice that jQuery exposes this createPositionalPseudo to easily have the positional pseudo facility we used to have in 1.6.